# asp.net mvc route with action after id and slug

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm adding a new route into my mvc web application and it's not working as desired. I was hoping someone could help me figure out where in the list it should go and maybe which defaults and/or constraints should be defined for it (in RouteConfig.cs).

The desired route would look like so:

`/controller/id/slug/action` e.g. mydomain.com/products/10/product-name/reviews

I've tried to define this route like so and have tried it as the 1st, 2nd and 3rd routes listed:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "AlternateRoute",
   url: "{controller}/{id}/{slug}/{action}",
   defaults: null,
   constraints: new { id = @"\d+", slug = @"[\w\-\d+]*" }
);
```

What's happening is after I add the above route, and browse to a page like `/products/10/product-name` - url's that were previously something like /products/create look like /products/10/product-name/create (but only on that page).

The only other routes I have are these 3 (defined in my routeConfig file):

/controller/id/slug

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "DefaultSlugRoute",
   url: "{controller}/{id}/{slug}",
   defaults: new { action = "Details", slug = "" },
   constraints: new { id = @"\d+", slug = @"[\w\-\d+]*" }
);
```

/controller/action/year/month

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "MonthlyArchiveRoute",
   url: "{controller}/{action}/{year}/{month}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "Archives", year = UrlParameter.Optional, month = UrlParameter.Optional },
   constraints: new { year = @"\d{4}", month = @"\d{2}" }
);
```

/controller/action/id (the standard one included w/ a new mvc project)

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "DefaultRoute",
   url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: I just discovered @Html.RouteLink where I can specify the route to use - this looks like a temporary fix of sorts.

Comment: Can't you just play around with the order that the MapRoutes are defined ??? that sounds like you want to check for a different one first then what you are doing